# How to get rid of row numbers, pd.read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am a complete beginner with Python. I am working on a assignment and I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the *row numbers* from my excel spreadsheet, while using `import pandas`.

This is what I get when I run the code:

```
0   $20,000,000 $159,000,000  
1    $9,900,000  $35,600,000  
2   $35,000,000  $45,000,000  
3    $9,900,000  $35,600,000  
4   $12,000,000   $9,400,000
```

But instead I just want:

```
$20,000,000  $159,000,000  
$9,900,000   $35,600,000  
$35,000,000  $45,000,000  
$9,900,000   $35,600,000  
$12,000,000  $9,400,000
```

This is inside of my main block for formatting:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = "movie_theme.xlsx"    

    # Formatting numbers (e.g. $1,000,000)
    pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.0f}'.format

    # Reading Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, convert_float = False)
```

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Do you really need that, or is it just for comfort?

Comment: Those row numbers are the index, whether they exist in your excel sheet or not they always exist, pandas will auto generate one even if there were none in the excel sheet, you can't override this behaviour. Also why is this an issue?

Answer (score 4):

Internally your dataframe always needs an index. If you get rid of the integer index another column has to be your index and you should only use a data column as your index if you need to for some special purpose.

When you write your dataframe to a file, e.g. with the `to_csv()` method, you can always specify the keyword `index=False` and you won't get that index written to your output.

Comment: `data_xls = pd.read_excel('excel/dsar.xlsx', f, index_col=None)`
`data_xls.to_csv(f'csv/{team["fileNames"][f]}.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df = df.set_index('Salary')
```

where `Salary` is the column name you want to be the index.

The row number is called the index.